# Accept decimals in form using 'step': decimal is not saving correctly in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, decimal

I'm trying to accept decimals in my form:

```
  <%= f.label :price %><br />
  <%= f.number_field :price, :step => 0.01 %>
```

But anytime I type in a number like 13.75 in the form from the client side, it'll round the number down to just $13.00. This is the code to display the price:

```
<%= number_to_currency(@product.price) %>
```

I don't think the number_to_currency method has anything to do with it but I guess it's worth noting.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that your price attribute is an integer in your database / model?

Comment: If that doesn't work, can you edit your question to include the params that are submitted to the server? Also, what happens when you remove the number_to_currency?

Comment: can you include the relevant portion of your schema.rb file?

Comment: Yeah, I set the price attribute as an integer which led to the problem. Changed it to a float. Thanks for the reply everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your schema.rb file you should have

```
t.float  "price"
```

instead of

```
t.integer  "price"
```

or

```
t.string  "price"
```

To do this, run `rails g migration change_data_type_for_fieldname`

Now a new migration file should appear in db/migrate:

```
class ChangeDataTypeForFieldName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

Fill it with proper names:

```
class ChangeDataTypeForFieldName < ActiveRecord::Migration
def self.up
    change_table :table_name do |t|
      t.change :field , :new_datatype
    end
  end
  def self.down
    change_table :table_name do |t|
      t.change :field, :old_data_type
    end
  end
end
```

Run `rake db:migrate`